# emberjs controller communication confuse

Tags: ember.js

I am using bootstrap with emberjs rc6. I want to show bootstrap modal using render helper. This is what I did:

avatar.hbs:

```
<aside class='avatar-aside'>
  **{{#if inEditModel}}
    {{render 'avatar/edit' model}}
  {{/if}}**
</aside>

<div class='avatar-inner'>
  {{#if canManage}}
    <a class='lnk-edit' href='#' **{{action 'edit'}}**>
      <img class='image-medium' {{bindAttr src='imageMediumPath'}}>
      <span class='bar-edit'><i class='icon-edit'></i></span>
    </a>
  {{else}}
    <img class='image-medium'
         {{bindAttr src='imageMediumPath'
                    alt='controllers.user.basicinfo.nickname'}}>
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

avatar_controller.js.coffee

```
Yu.AvatarController = Em.ObjectController.extend
  inEditModel: false

  edit: ->
    @set 'inEditModel', true
```

avatar/edit_view.js.coffee

```
Yu.AvatarEditView = Em.View.extend
  tagName:    'section'
  classNames: 'avatar-edit modal fade'.w()

  didInsertElement: ->
    @$().modal
      backdrop: 'static'
      keyboard: false

  willDestroyElement: ->
    @$().modal 'hide'
```

avatar/edit_controller.js.coffee

```
Yu.AvatarEditController = Em.ObjectController.extend
  needs: 'avatar flashEmbeded'.w()

  close: ->
    @get('controllers.avatar').set 'inEditModel', false

  cancel: ->
    @get('controllers.avatar').set 'inEditModel', false

  update: ->
    userId  =  @get 'userId'

    Yu.Avatar.
      update(userId).

      done((response) =>
        @get('controllers.avatar').set 'inEditModel', false
      ).

      fail((response) =>
        errormsg = $.parseJSON(response.responseText).errors[0]
        @get('controllers.flashEmbeded').notify 'errormsg', errormsg
      )
```

As you can see, I want to show or hide avatar/edit template by switch inEditModel of avatar controller. Till now, what I know is when I do 
            @get('controllers.avatar').set 'inEditModel', false in avatar edit controller, inEditModel in avatar controller does not change. *I wonder if I got two different instance of avatar controller.* What thing I did wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are running in some binding issues here, what might help is trying to define things more like this:

```
Yu.AvatarEditController = Em.ObjectController.extend
  needs: 'avatar flashEmbeded'.w()
  avatarControllerBinding: 'controllers.avatar'

  close: ->
    @get('avatarController').set 'inEditModel', false

  cancel: ->
    @get('avatarController').set 'inEditModel', false
  ...
```

As for the bootstrap modal, you should definitely have a look at this addon https://github.com/emberjs-addons/ember-bootstrap. I've used it successfully myself and it is up todate with ember.js rc6.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I dont know if it is binding issue. What I think now is "needs only works for singleton controllers" : http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/documentation-needs-api-is-it-only-for-singleton-controllers/911/3 In my case, I render the avatar template inside user template: {{render 'avatar' avatar}} This created a instance of avatar controller. I have put {{controller}} and {{controllers.avatar}}in avatar.hbs avatar/edit.hbs They return different id.